# I just cant get to open WSDL file in Eclipse J2EE Galileo

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, eclipse-plugin

As far as i can see, i have the option of creating web services and WSDL file in Galileo.

Also, Looking here there is the Eclipse WSDL viewer : http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Introduction_to_the_WSDL_Editor

How can i open a WSDL file in Eclipse ? If i just browse and open the file, nothing happens.

Someone please help, this is really frustrating as i cannot seem to find any information online regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

never mind, i figured it out.
The welcome screen was blocking my view of the already opened file.

For those who have the same problem, just click on the 'X' on the tab in the welcome screen and you are good to go !